# makecell: how to reduce the line spacing in multiline cells?

Tags: tables, line-spacing

The following LaTeX source code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    foobar                    & 0  \\
    foo                       & 1  \\
    \makecell[tl]{bar plus \\
                  other    \\
                  stuff}      & 2  \\
    baz                       & 3  \\
    qux                       & 4  \\
    quux                      & 5  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

...produces the following rendering:

[image]

This is almost what I want, but I would like that the spacing between the lines in the multiline cell ("bar plus other stuff") be noticeably smaller than the spacing between table's rows.

Therefore, I tried adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` right before the `\begin{tabular}[ll}` line<sup>1</sup>; i.e.:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    foobar                    & 0  \\
    foo                       & 1  \\
    \makecell[tl]{bar plus \\
                  other    \\
                  stuff}      & 2  \\
    baz                       & 3  \\
    qux                       & 4  \\
    quux                      & 5  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Here's what the results look like:

[image]

After seeing this, I realized that I would like to keep the between-rows spacing as it was before (i.e. as it was before I added `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}`), and instead make the spacing between the lines in the multiline cell *narrower*<sup>2</sup>.

I have read, and re-read, and re-read once more, [the documentation for the `makecell` package](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf), but I just cannot make heads or tails of it.  (Nothing that I have ***copied verbatim*** from that documentation *will even compile*, let alone do what I'm after.)  I'm sure that *somewhere in that documentation* is the information I need to change the spacing *between* the lines in the multiline cell.  Could someone please spell it out for me?<sup>3</sup>

---

**EDIT:** I learned from [@Bernard's helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644939/7792) that the reason nothing worked for me when I tried customizing `makecell`'s behavior is that I was missing the `\usepackage{array}` directive.  With this knowledge in hand, I tried to get the tighest possible spacing between the lines of a multiline cell as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}%
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    foobar                    & 0  \\
    foo                       & 1  \\
    \makecell[tl]{bar plus \\
                  other    \\
                  stuff}      & 2  \\
    baz                       & 3  \\
    qux                       & 4  \\
    quux                      & 5  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The results:

[image]

Granted, the between-line spacing resulting from *this* particular directive may be a bit *too tight*; probably a slightly looser spacing (but still tighter than the spacing between rows) would be better.  Nevertheless, I use this extreme case to better illustrate the remaining problem: namely the newly added directive

```
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}%
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}}
```

...affects not only the spacing *between* the lines in the multiline cell (as desired), but *also* the spacing between the last line of the multiline cell ("stuff") and the next row ("baz  3"), which is definitely not what I want<sup>4</sup>.

Is there a way to tweak this latest version (based on `makecell`<sup>5</sup>) so that only the spacing ***between*** the lines in the multiline cells is reduced, but all the other vertical spacing, including the spacing between the last line of the multiline cell ("stuff") and the next row ("baz  3") are preserved?

---

**EDIT 2:** Actually, the issue in my last edit can be understood more clearly if one replaces all the entries in the first column with a common string, e.g. "0000".  Hence, if we change the document's body to

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    0000                      & 0  \\
    0000                      & 1  \\
    \makecell[tl]{0000 \\
                  0000 \\
                  0000}       & 2  \\
    0000                      & 3  \\
    0000                      & 4  \\
    0000                      & 5  \\
\end{tabular}
```

...leaving everything else unchanged, the result looks like this:

[image]

In words: the newly added directive *does* reduce the spacing between the lines in the multiline cell, but it *also* reduces the spacing between the last line of the multiline cell and the next row (the one with "3" in the second colum).  Granted, this latter spacing is slightly larger than the former, but it is still *significantly* smaller than the spacing between the remaining rows.

---

**EDIT 3:** As I mentioned earlier, I have not found a combination of parameters that for the new directive that will produce the desired results.  For example, the result I get from the source code below (where I've changed `\extrarowheight`'s parameter to `1pt`) looks to me *exactly the same* as the one I showed in the last display above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}%
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}} %% NB: I see no difference in results
                                %% between 0pt and 1pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    0000                      & 0  \\
    0000                      & 1  \\
    \makecell[tl]{0000 \\
                  0000 \\
                  0000}       & 2  \\
    0000                      & 3  \\
    0000                      & 4  \\
    0000                      & 5  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> If I understand correctly, the way I've added the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` directive means that it will affect all the subsequent code, up until the end of the file.  Just curious: is there a way that I can limit the effect of this directive to just the one table?</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I realize that making the line spacing in the multiline cell narrower will make the text look cramped.  That's OK.  In practice, I expect multiline cells will be quite rare.  Therefore, I prefer a solution that keeps the normal case (rows consisting entirely of single-line cells) looking nice, even if the occasional multiline cell ends up looking cramped.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> Asking such a question is deeply embarrassing for me.  I have been programming for a living for >30 years, and I have been using LaTex pretty much all that time.  I have written dozens of reports and scientific papers, and one doctoral dissertation, with LaTeX.  I have read books on LaTeX cover-to-cover.  Even with all this experience and study, I *still* find LaTeX *utterly mystifying*.  (And please let's not talk about TeX...)  This is particularly true of the documentation of the typical LaTeX package, as illustrated by my complete failure to find *even an approximation* to the answer to my question in the documentation for the `makecell` package.  I hope that, in addition to solving my immediate problem, the answer to this question may teach me a bit how to find my way around LaTeX documentation.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> For what it's worth, I have not found a combination of parameter values to stick into the `\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{...}\setlength\extrarowheight{...}}` directive that simultaneously solves the original problem, and whose result does not suffer from the defect illustrated in the last display above.</sup>

<sup><sup>5</sup> I realize, after reading [@Zarko's also very helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644924/7792), that `makecell` is probably not the best package for what I'm trying to do, and therefore, that by insisting on using `makecell` for this, I am probably making this problem unnecessarily difficult.  Unfortunately, it appears that `tabularray` requires a newer installation of LaTeX than what I have in my system.  This means that, until I figure out how to upgrade the LaTeX installation on my system, something that has eluded me for weeks already, I am basically stuck with `makecell`.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this solution with only `makecell` befit you?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, makecell}
    \renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}%
    \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}}

    \begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        foobar & 0 \\
        foo & 1 \\
        \makecell[tl]{bar plus \\
                      other \\
                      stuff} & 2 \\
        baz & 3 \\
        qux & 4 \\
        quux & 5 \\
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I now realize, after reading your answer, that the reason nothing was working for me when I tried to tweak the separations for the `makecell` package is that I had somehow overlooked that `makecell` requires the `array` package!

Comment: That said, I confess that I accepted your solution partly because I feel guilty for being such a whiny, picky pest...  If truth be told, your answer doesn't quite give me what I want, but the problem is obscured by the fact that your solution kept the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}`, which I had explicitly rejected in my original question.  If you remove this directive from your solution, you will see the problem that remains; namely, that the spacing between the last line of the multiline cell and the next row is too narrow.  In other words, ...

Comment: ...your solution affects more than the spacing ***between*** the lines in the multiline cell.  Is there a way to reduce *only* this spacing, leaving all other spacing as is?

Comment: @kjo: normally, it affects only the vertical spacing in`\makecell`.

Comment: Bernard, I don't get your last point.  FWIW, I've added an **EDIT** to my post that I hope more clearly describes what I alluded to in my previous two comments.

Comment: @kjo: it seems that using in \cellset `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}` in the place of 0pt makes the vertical spacing with the following row normal.

Comment: OK, that's puzzling.  I get the same results whether I set that parameter to `1pt` or `0pt`.  FWIW, I just posted, in a further **EDIT**, the exact LaTeX code I used for this test.  I wonder if the difference between our observations has something to do with the fact that my LaTeX installation is somewhat decrepit.  I am coming around to accepting that maybe I should solve this problem first, before continuing to bang my head against the wall...

Comment: I had tested with your last code (0000 in each row). Mayb- e you should indeed update your installation. Mine is an up-to-date MiKTeX.  Note that `makecell` is not the only possibility – `stackengine`  is another one.

Answer (score 4):

With use of the `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{cells=l,
             rowsep=3pt}
    foobar                      & 0  \\
    foo                         & 1  \\
    {bar plus\\other\\stuff}    & 2  \\
    baz                         & 3  \\
    qux                         & 4  \\
    quux                        & 5  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If you like to have lines in multi lines cell even closer, than you can experiment with changes of `\linespread` in table:

```
\begin{tblr}{cells=l,
             rowsep=3pt,
             rows = {font=\linespread{0.9}\selectfont} % <---
             }
```

With above settings you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sure this is the way to go.  Unfortunately, it appears that my installation of LaTeX is too old for `tabularray` (at least that's what the error message I get tells me).  I have been trying to upgrade my LaTeX for weeks now, without success.  This is yet another example of my all-around inability to work with LaTeX/TeX.  For the time being, at least, I think I'm stuck with `makecell`.

Comment: You can use Overleaf. There is an old `tabularray` but for this simple examle it should work. BTW, upgrade your installation should not be big deal. Use wizard, which is part of your LaTeX installation (for example at MiKTeX is called "Console".

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Overleaf.  BTW, I cannot find any executable file with the string "wizard" or the string "console" (case-insensitive search) in the basename and the perl-regex `/tex\b/i` in the path.  My system is a Debian Linux workstation.  I typically have no problem with software installation and management on this machine.  LaTeX/TeX is an exception to this.  In fact, to call it an "exception" puts it mildly.  A "catastrophe" is closer to the mark.

Comment: Debian hasn't "console", it is MiKTEX tool/utility  for add new packages (if needed), or upgrade existing package etc. Similar tool exist for Debian, but I'm not familiar with it. Sorry.